# Spring Boot: getting query string parameters and request body in AuditApplicationEvent listener

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, auditing, http-trace

Spring Boot REST app here. I'm trying to configure Spring Boot request auditing to log each and every HTTP request that any resources/controllers receive with the following info:

1. I need to see in the logs the exact HTTP URL (path) that was requested by the client, including the HTTP method **and any query string parameters**; and
2. If there is a request body (such as with a POST or PUT) I need to see the contents of that body in the logs as well

My best attempt so far:

```
@Component
public class MyAppAuditor {
    private Logger logger;

    @EventListener
    public void handleAuditEvent(AuditApplicationEvent auditApplicationEvent) {
        logger.info(auditApplicationEvent.auditEvent);
    }
}

public class AuditingTraceRepository implements TraceRepository {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher

    @Override
    List<Trace> findAll() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("We don't expose trace information via /trace!");
    }

    @Override
    void add(Map<String, Object> traceInfo) {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        AuditEvent traceRequestEvent = new AuditEvent(new Date(), "SomeUser", 'http.request.trace', traceInfo);
        AuditApplicationEvent traceRequestAppEvent = new AuditApplicationEvent(traceRequestEvent);

        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(traceRequestAppEvent);
    }
}
```

However at runtime if I use the following curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/v1/data/profiles?continent=NA&country=US&isMale=0&height=1.5&dob=range('1980-01-01','1990-01-01')'
```

Then I only see the following log messages (where `MyAppAuditor` send audit events):

```
{ "timestamp" : "14:09:50.516", "thread" : "qtp1293252487-17", "level" : "INFO", "logger" : "com.myapp.ws.shared.auditing.MyAppAuditor", "message" : {"timestamp":"2018-06-29T18:09:50+0000","principal":"SomeUser","type":"http.request.trace","data":{"method":"GET","path":"/v1/data/profiles","headers":{"request":{"User-Agent":"curl/7.54.0","Host":"localhost:9200","Accept":"*/*","Content-Type":"application/json"},"response":{"X-Frame-Options":"DENY","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate","X-Content-Type-Options":"nosniff","Pragma":"no-cache","Expires":"0","X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block","X-Application-Context":"application:9200","Date":"Fri, 29 Jun 2018 18:09:50 GMT","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","status":"200"}},"timeTaken":"89"}} }
```

So as you can see, the auditor is picking up the base path (`/v1/data/profiles`) but is not logging any of the query string parameters. I also see a similar absence of request body info when I hit POST or PUT endpoints that do require a request body (JSON).

**What do I need to do to configure these classes (or other Spring classes/configs) so that I get the level of request auditing that I'm looking for?**

Comment: I posted what I think would be the best solution for this. Let me know if you have any questions about the solution and if it needs any clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, Actuator makes it very easy to configure those `Trace` events.

**Adding *parameters* to Trace info**

You can [take a look](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/dd08c31b9a5c21da31ecc4e9408e33445dd2ea73/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/trace/TraceProperties.java#L67) at all of the  options. You'll notice the defaults (`line 42`) are:

```
Include.REQUEST_HEADERS, 
Include.RESPONSE_HEADERS, 
Include.COOKIES, 
Include.ERRORS, 
Include.TIME_TAKEN
```

So you'll need to also add `Include.PARAMETERS` and anything else you'd like to have in the trace. To configure that, there's a configuration property for that **`management.trace.include`**.

So to get what you want (i.e. `parameters`), plus the defaults, you'd have:

`management.trace.include = parameters, request-headers, response-headers, cookies, errors, time-taken`

**Adding *request body* to Trace info**

In order to get the `body`, you're going to have to add in this `Bean` to your `Context`:

```
@Component
public class WebRequestTraceFilterWithPayload extends WebRequestTraceFilter {

    public WebRequestTraceFilterWithPayload(TraceRepository repository, TraceProperties properties) {
        super(repository, properties);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Object> getTrace(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> trace = super.getTrace(request);

        String body = null;
        try {
            body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        if(body != null) {
            trace.put("body", body);
        }

        return trace;
    }

}
```

The above code will override the `AutoConfigure'd` `WebRequestTraceFilter` bean (which, because it is `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` will give deference to your custom bean), and pull the extra payload property off of the `request` then add it to to the `Map` properties that get published to your `TraceRepository`!

**Summary**

1. *Request Parameters* can be added to `TraceRepository trace events` by via the `management.trace.include` property
2. The *Request Body* can be added to the `TraceRepository trace events` by creating an extended `Bean` to read the `body` off of the HTTP request and supplementing the trace events